# Thread.Join status/breakout

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Hi is there any possible way to get the status of the threads from a Thread.Join, or can i make a breakout from a Thread.Join at a specified period?
For eg:

I have a loop that have n-jobs, i've got 3 free cores for 3 parallel threads, and after Joining the 3 threads, i wonder if there's a way to check if a thread has done it's job to start another job in it's place.
I want to keep the 3 cores working all time, not to wait for all threads to stop and then start another 3 of them.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, and most likely best, solution is to use the threadpool. The threadpool automatically scales based on available processors and cores.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => TaskOne());
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => TaskTwo());
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => TaskThree());
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => TaskFour());
```

If you *need* to do this the hard way, you could keep a queue of pending tasks and a list of currently running tasks, and use a timeout for the `Join()` call so that it returns false if the thread is not ready.

I can't think of any reason to prefer the complex to the simple solution, but there might be one, of course.

```
var MAX_RUNNING = 3;
var JOIN_TIMEOUT_MS = 50;
var waiting = new Queue<ThreadStart>();
var running = new List<Thread>();   

waiting.Enqueue(new ThreadStart(TaskOne));
waiting.Enqueue(new ThreadStart(TaskTwo));
waiting.Enqueue(new ThreadStart(TaskThree));
waiting.Enqueue(new ThreadStart(TaskFour));


while (waiting.Any() || running.Any())
{
    while (running.Count < MAX_RUNNING && waiting.Any())
    {
        var next = new Thread(waiting.Dequeue());
        next.Start();
        running.Add(next);
    }

    for (var i = running.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        var t = running[i];

        if(t.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped) {
            running.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
        }

        if (t.Join(JOIN_TIMEOUT_MS))
        {
            running.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: By the way, you might want to loop twice through the tasks, first removing any stopped ones, and _then_ `join` ing them in turn. If the first task in the list is stopped, this will prevent a join timeout from elapsing before the next tasks starts. But the code will also be a bit harder to follow. All in all, go for the simple solution :)

Comment: The main reason i don't use ThreadPool is that i don't have any idea how to block MainThread from running the rest code after calling the ThreadPool.
And thank you for your time! :)

Comment: Create a `Task` object in each work item, and do `Task.WaitAll()` in the main thread? Means you have to do a try/catch in each work item to fail the task, but that's not too hard.